# How to make screenreader read the aria-label of a button while clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accessibility

I'm working on improving the accessibility of an HTML page. I have a "refresh" button. Is it possible that every time I click the button, the screenreader will read out "refreshing".
This is my HTML code:

```
<button id="refresh_btn" title="refresh the content" aria-label="refresh" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
```

Comment: Does it actually refresh the page or just the content?

Comment: It's just for content not the whole page

Answer (score 0):

You have to investigate the [`aria-live` attribute:](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-live)

```
<div aria-live="polite" id="ele"></div>
```

Each time you press the button you can populate the above tag with the text you want using javascript:

```
<div aria-live="polite" id="ele">Loading</div>
```